# How to make a timer + stopwatch app in kivy

Tags: python, timer, kivy, stopwatch

I am trying to develop my first app with kivy but I am experiencing difficulties during development because I am still a beginner and I have no idea how to do it. The goal I have in mind is to create timer plus stopwatch app.

The timer must be very simple with a single button. Pressing the button the first time the timer starts, pressing it the second time it stops.

Later I would like to pass the time recorded with the timer to a stopwatch that puts it in a loop continuously.

For example:

1. the timer is activated
2. after 20 seconds I stop it
3. the stopwatch begins to decrease the value 20 to 0 every second continuously and repeat in a loop.

I tried to have a look around but I can't find anything to lean on. A valid project for the timer is the following

```
import kivy 
from kivy.app import App 
kivy.require('1.9.0') 
from kivy.lang import Builder 
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty 
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout 
from kivy.clock import Clock 

Builder.load_string(''' 

<MainWidget>: 

    # Assigning the alignment to buttons 
    BoxLayout: 
        orientation: 'vertical' 

        # Create Button 
        
        Button: 
            text: 'start' 
            on_press: root.start() 
            
        Button: 
            text: 'stop' 
            on_press: root.stop() 
            
        Button: 
            text: 'Reset' 
            on_press: root.number = 0 

    # Create the Label 
    Label: 
        text: str(round(root.number)) 
        text_size: self.size 
        halign: 'center' 
        valign: 'middle' 
''') 

class MainWidget(BoxLayout): 
    
    number = NumericProperty() 
    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs): 
        super(MainWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)  
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.increment_time, .1) 
        self.increment_time(0) 


    def increment_time(self, interval): 
        self.number += .1


    def start(self): 
        
        Clock.unschedule(self.increment_time) 
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.increment_time, .1) 

    
    def stop(self): 
        Clock.unschedule(self.increment_time) 


class TimeApp(App): 
    def build(self): 
        return MainWidget() 


TimeApp().run()
```

But in any case it has three buttons while I would only like one that acts as both a "start" and a "stop". And I have no idea how to pass the time recorde with timer to the stopwatch.

Please, if there is someone who can help me I would be truly grateful. I don't know who else to turn to and I'm going crazy about this.
Thanks in advance!

P.S.: sorry for my horrible english, i don't speak english and i tried to be as clear as possible

Comment: Show us what you have attempted. The code you posted is part of a [kivy tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-create-a-stopwatch-using-clock-object-in-kivy-using-kv-file/?ref=rp).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I made a timer app in python and i want to implement it in kivy, but i don't know how. The code i wrote was:                                                         import time
start = time.time()
time.sleep(4)
finish = time.time()
elapsed = finish - start
print(elapsed)
And then i can pass elapsed to a stopwatch, but in kivy?